# Build library and include CSS files but not test files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs

I am currently working on a React library. When I run build the css files are ignored. I added the flag `--copy-files` to the build script, now it copies the css files and also the test files.

I currently have this in the script:
`babel src/ --out-dir lib --ignore spec.js --copy-files`

How do I setup the build script so it ignores the test files and copy every other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing script happened to be working all I needed to do was delete the already existing compiled `lib` directory which for a reason still had the tests folder/files included.

For future purposes, if you want to exclude a file from being compiled or copied over, add them to the include flag like so: `--ignore spec.js`.

I hope this helps anyone that run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
babel src/ --out-dir lib --ignore spec.js --copy-files
```

the code above should be working. Probably you can delete the `lib` folder and try build again to see if the test files are still there.